# CROSS-DOMAIN - Retrieve Page Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a project here at work where we need a specific value from another domain I do not have access to change (So I can't do nested iframes, or CORS).  We need to keep Session/Cookie state the same to get the required data from the page as the token changes based on the user on the page.  So a server side solution wouldn't work.

What is the best way to go about this, the following is what the page source is in it's entirety.
I need to retrieve the FF321332 value

```
{"<!--":"","token":"FF321332","expire":1317448445,"":"--><body onload=document.body.innerHTML=clear>"}
```

Some things I've tried so far are Dynamic Script Tags "It throws a JS error Unexpected token : error, Jquery (.getScript ) this throws the same error, any other form of .get or xhr will throw a Cross Domain Error.

I feel like I was on the right track with the .getScript or Dynamic Script Tags as it almost wants to read it in.  But if I can get around the Unexpected token error and just read it in as text (if this is possible) I can just parse out the variable as normal text.

Any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP allows you to do what you are trying to do. Check out the jQuery doc on how to make your .get use JSONP to side step the browser cross-domain enforcement.

Essentially, when you do $.getJSON, if the url has a piece that says "callback=" + whatever, then it will treat it as jsonp instead of the standard getjson.

Good luck.

Comment: yeh I forgot to mention in my post that I tried this as well, it basically throws the same "Unexpected token : " error that .getScript and dynamic script tags do.  it appears that it's trying to run it as a script.
     
     $.getJSON(url, function(json){
          alert("JSON DATA: " + json);
     });

I could setup a mock up of the page I'm looking for, I can really give the exact page due to company policy

Comment: get me a jsfiddle to see it if you can.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TcsQj/) - here is a mock up for ya,  I hope you are more successful then me!  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Good news... it is working... but the browser doesn't like to receive the JSON in the format that you have it. If you open your Developer Tools in Chrome, there is a "Network" tab. Click on that and reload the page. You will see the request to the test.php page. You will see the response. It doesn't like to see the response like that. If you were to simply put it in an array (wrap with brakets), it would work for you. Not sure what else to tell you. It is working though. If you want to see my screenshots, let me know.

Comment: yeh I don't have control over that server, I'm wondering if there is a way to coax the browser to accept it somehow into a usable state?

Comment: That is a great question... and can't get it to work. I think that you should ask that question on here... see if someone else knows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can get past the error using script tags, because normally, once the "javascript"  specified in the src attribute gets downloaded it also gets executed. You said you can't use a server side solution because you need to preserve state?

Well you can do that using curl and a cookie jar. Never tried this before but in theory it should work:
Basically all you need to do is setup a curl request to the remote domain to accept cookies and store those in a file (cookie jar) and then do a second request to fetch the page passing along the previous obtained cookies.

Give it a try, maybe it will work.