# Handle Malformed Remote JSONP Response

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

this is a continuation of my original question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606595/cross-domain-retrieve-page-source)

You can see through my rather lengthy conversion with aaronfrost that we determined the jquery was loading in the .php (as seen on the network tab in CHROME) however it's trying to be ran as a script immediately.  My question is where or not it's possible to load that in as plain text and simply then do a js parse out the needed data.   Doesn't have to be jQuery this was just the route we were going in this example.  I've also tried with the following code and recieve the exact same "Unexpected token" error.  I think if there were a way to just some how handle the malformed JSON client side we would be able to make this work, in a ugly sort of way.

If javascript doesn't work do you think going the route of a java applet (preserve client cookies, non-server side) would achieve the desired end result i'm looking for?

```
 <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>

 <script type="application/javascript">
var url = 'http://www.makecashnow.mobi/jsonp_test.php';

//<!-[CDATA[
    function JSONscriptRequest(fullUrl) {
        // REST request path
        this.fullUrl = fullUrl; 
        // Keep IE from caching requests
        //this.noCacheIE = '&noCacheIE=' + (new Date()).getTime();
        // Get the DOM location to put the script tag
        this.headLoc = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);
        // Generate a unique script tag id
        this.scriptId = 'JscriptId' + JSONscriptRequest.scriptCounter++;
    }

    // Static script ID counter
    JSONscriptRequest.scriptCounter = 1;

    // buildScriptTag method
    //
    JSONscriptRequest.prototype.buildScriptTag = function () {

        // Create the script tag
        this.scriptObj = document.createElement("script");

        // Add script object attributes
        this.scriptObj.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        this.scriptObj.setAttribute("charset", "utf-8");
        //this.scriptObj.setAttribute("src", this.fullUrl + this.noCacheIE);
        this.scriptObj.setAttribute("src", this.fullUrl);
        this.scriptObj.setAttribute("id", this.scriptId);
    }

    // removeScriptTag method
    // 
    JSONscriptRequest.prototype.removeScriptTag = function () {
        // Destroy the script tag
        this.headLoc.removeChild(this.scriptObj);  
    }

    // addScriptTag method
    //
    JSONscriptRequest.prototype.addScriptTag = function () {
        // Create the script tag
        this.headLoc.appendChild(this.scriptObj);
    }

    var obj = new JSONscriptRequest(url);
    obj.buildScriptTag();
    obj.addScriptTag();
//]]>

</script>
```

Comment: Just wondering, this isn't an answer, but have you considered an intermediary like a server running a cURL to the third party page?

Comment: if you see the original post that was one of the requirements to use only client side scripting/solution.  So that removes chances of using cURL.  Boss likes to make my life very rough at times. lol

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but you're not actually getting a JSON-encoded response according to your example you link to: http://jsfiddle.net/TcsQj/ Hence, your error. You would need to use the actual response text, not the parse JSON response. Additionally, that's not what I would call a "rather lengthy conversation" in the other question under Aaron Frost's answer.

Comment: well as in rather lengthy I meant StackOverflow yelled at me to create a Conversation thread lol.  Anyways, how exactly could you get the responseText without violating cross-domain origin.  As from my tests getJSON doesn't have a .responseText method

Comment: I don't think you can without it being a JSON object in jQuery (at least I couldn't find anywhere that specified you could). You might look in the jQuery source (or the source for the library you included above) and see if you can replicate and capture the actual responseText in a custom plugin/object. And disregard SO's nagware at this time; you don't even have enough rep to use chat yet. Sometimes, it's unavoidable and the nag suggests a chat only after x number of comments, AFAICT. (I've had 50+ comments in an answer, which is probably what the nag is for... `;)`)

Comment: The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is going to prevent you from doing what you're trying to do.  If you cannot get the other site to respond with a proper JSONP response, then you're just out of luck (unless you build a server-side intermediary).

Comment: if you run the example from either this post or the original and run fiddler along side it you'll see the response is there from the server just fine.  Makes me wonder if Jared is on the right track with a jQuery 'Hack'/plugin.